# USB wireless desktop combo keeps resetting "reset full speed USB device"

Tags: linux, usb, desktop, reset, wireless

I am running Linux 3.0.35_4.1.0 on a custom freescale i.mx6 board similar to the Boundary devices nitrogen6x board.

The issue i'm having is that when I connect the wireless transceiver dongle for the "Microsoft Wireless Desktop 2000", the mouse works intermittently, and the keyboard does not work at all.

The HID ID of the transceiver is 045e:0745

The error in the terminal is:

```
root@devonit-tc3:~# 
root@devonit-tc3:~# [ 59.225756] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 61.050541] usb 1-1: new full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
[ 61.211567] usb 1-1: device v045e p0745 is not supported
[ 61.224000] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input3
[ 61.237194] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input0
[ 61.261561] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/input/input4
[ 61.277992] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input1
[ 61.327164] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/input/input5
[ 61.344711] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input2
[ 62.560605] usb 1-1: reset full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
[ 63.940594] usb 1-1: reset full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
[ 64.230571] usb 1-1: reset full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
[ 65.590572] usb 1-1: reset full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
[ 65.880556] usb 1-1: reset full speed USB device number 3 using fsl-ehci
```

Comment: I found the solution to this issue in the following posts: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-902516-start-0.html and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=91496

The issue involves USB scheduling. A kernel configuration option " Improved Transaction Translator scheduling" (CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED) was necessary.

Comment: I have a spam of similar `kernel: usb 3-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd` messages in my journal and my mouse also intermittently works, moreover the system clock seems to be flawed (running `top` refreshes every 0.1 seconds even if it is set to refresh every 3 seconds). Can I activate improved Transaction Translator scheduling without recompiling the whole kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kernel configuration option "Improved Transaction Translator scheduling" (CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED) was necessary.

This allowed the Microsoft Wireless Desktop 2000 to work flawlessly with our device.